# A way to get unlock event in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen

Is there a way to receive something like `PHONE_UNLOCKED` (with a `BroadcastReceiver` of some kind)?

I have a service running that shows a `Toast` when the screen is turned on. Unfortunately a few phones don't show it until they're unlocked. Most of the times the `Toast` message is already gone then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - detect phone unlock event, not screen on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is a Broadcast Receiver Action **[ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)**  here is the implementation of ACTION_USER_PRESENT and ACTION_SHUTDOWN

add this to your application **Manifests**

```
<receiver android:name=".UserPresentBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

to receive the actions

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class UserPresentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        /*Sent when the user is present after 
         * device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone)
         * */
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

        }
        /*Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the device 
         * is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping)
         * */
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {

        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
[see](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)

Comment: What would I need ACTION_SHUTDOWN for?

Comment: I'm going to try it out tomorrow, it's late in the night here

Comment: @Chathura Thanks for your answer, but please try to e specific. If there's no need of "Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN", please remove those kind of 'dead code'. There are many 'android freshers' who gets confused. By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: that's why I put the comment. This will help to someone

Comment: action user present is fired after the system lock is unlocked and home screen appears. but i want to display my screen as a lock screen just after the device is unlocked before device lock screen. please suggest .

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you won't receive the broadcast from Android O. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Comment: using this method can we detect user unlock feature means when user unlock the phone i want to notify my app ?

Comment: I tried this but it's not working on Chromebook, is there any other workaround for Chromebook?