# Ideas for my app that runs in the background

Tags: java, android, background-service

I'm developing an app that runs in the background that essentially snaps a front facing photo every time the phone is successfully/unsuccessfully unlocked. This isn't an original idea, but I'm developing it as a final project for my college android programming course, with no intent to sell this app. I have a general idea how I am going to go about this via some research but I keep running across a problem.

I know that it is hard and bad practice to run an app continuously in the background, so the idea is you put the app to sleep and set an alarm. My problem is that if the would be phone-snooper were to get really lucky, they could access the phone in between the alarms, and the owner of the phone would never know. I talked with my professor, and he proposed a couple ideas, but we could not come up with a definite solution, so I'm asking opinions here. Any idea how to subvert this dilemma? Thanks a ton.

Comment: try to ask more specific questions.

Comment: I think that is a reasonably specific question: what is a good way to set up an alarm that doesn't miss  when someone unlocks the phone...

Comment: We cannot do your homework/project for you. We are here to help you with any specific question you may have regarding your code/implementation.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20225681/1159056)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is probably not appropriate for the problem. You can't "time" unpredictable events (like someone attempting to unlock a phone). Or else it's not clear how you are setting the alarm.

You should change the approach to an event-based approach.

Either provide a service for a lock-screen app so that it can use your code to capture a pic by sending login attempt events to it. You write that and provide an SDK/API.

Or else create your own lock screen app with your feature:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own