# Android app launches on opening lockscreen

Tags: android, locking, keypad

I want my app  or a part (any activity) of the app to be launched on opening the **lockscreen,** i.e, when we ***unlock the keypad*** of our phone, my activity should start running.. Thanks in advance. :D [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD9lM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one 
[A way to get unlock event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224637/a-way-to-get-unlock-event-in-android)

It's using ACTION_USER_PRESENT receiver, but stil could help you.

Answer (score 0):

To unlock the keyguard.

add this permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    //  createWakeLocks();

            KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            boolean isKeyguardUp = kgm.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
            KeyguardLock kgl = kgm.newKeyguardLock("QuickPopup");

            if (isKeyguardUp) {
                kgl.disableKeyguard();
                isKeyguardUp = false;
            }
            getWindow().addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            getWindow().addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
//          getWindow()
//                  .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow()
                    .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            //wakeDevice();
 }
```