# Making an app which can track the time when user unlocks his phone

Tags: android

I want to create an android app which will tell me when I have unlocked my phone in past day also track the location where I have unlocked the phone using GPS. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes it is achievable. Start writing the code.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask is there any android api that I can use here? I know about **android.app.usage**, but that does not give me the information when user unlocked his phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) for receiving system messages. For checking when the device is unlocked you can use [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) intent filter for you receiver. Start a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) when your receiver receives broadcast from system and log your current location data.

This might help in the way - [A way to get unlock event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224637/a-way-to-get-unlock-event-in-android)