# is there any way to develop first screen contents by flutter?

Tags: flutter, smartphone

I'm just trying to develop first-screen contents application which acts like...

If you unlock your smartphone, this application show up and show its contents like today's whether, a sentence of bible, etc.. before smartphone's own contents. And then if you touch the screen one more time, you can use your smartphone.

So it seems like.. a splash screen of smartphone, instead an application.

Because I'm not good at English, I don't know how to call this technique by English.

So what I want to know is anything. The name of this technique.. helpful flutter widget.. or any reference about this written by flutter.

Thank you.

Comment: please try this feature that my help you :- https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9

Answer (score 0):

**For Android:**

You can't listen to phone unlock event after Android 8.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225681/10874380

**For iOS:**

I'm not very familiar with iOS restrictions, but as far as I know, apps on iOS has no way to know the phone is unlocked. Also, ios apps can't open without user tapping on it.