# BroadcastReceiver, unlock successful of default lockscreen, Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way (Broadcast Receiver) from where I can detect that Lock is successful or not for example (Pattern Lock, Simple Lock)

For example I want to make an applicaiton in that I want to open browser with URL when LOCK is successful

I have made **custom lock screen** in that when user open lock he will be redirect to browser with specific url,

**It is working fine when there is no any system default lock**

MyCustomLockScreen (LOCK SUCCESS)(INTENT WITH URL)--------->OPEN BROWSWER with URL

**but if there is any default system lock**

MyCustomLockScreen (LOCK SUCCESS)(INTENT WITH URL)--- > DEFAULT SCREENLOCK ------>OPEN BROWSWER but no any URL

So If I get **broadcast of successfully unlock device**, so I think I will override broadcast receiver and can handle.

Comment: this should give You a direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on