# What's the difference between isDeviceLocked and isKeyguardSecure in android's KeyguardManager?

Tags: android, api, locking, lockscreen, keyguard

Below is excerpted from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html

**public boolean isDeviceLocked ()**

*Returns whether the device is currently locked and requires a PIN, pattern or password to unlock. Returns true if unlocking the device currently requires a PIN, pattern or password.*

**public boolean isKeyguardSecure ()**

*Return whether the keyguard requires a password to unlock. Returns true if keyguard is secure.*

What's the difference between `isDeviceLocked` and `isKeyguardSecure`?

Comment: Well, if you have a password, both methods return `true`. If you have a PIN or pattern, just `isDeviceLocked` returns `true` and if you have no lock, both return `false`. I guess `isKeyguardSecure` has its function because PIN and pattern can be bypassed more easily.

Comment: Why compare `isDeviceLocked()` with `isKeyguardSecure()`? The pendant to  `isDeviceLocked()` is `isKeyguardLocked()`, the *keyguard api being older and also taking SIM Pin into account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**public boolean isDeviceLocked ()**

This method takes the current UI state of the Lockscreen into account.

So if a secure Screen Lock has been setup, it will contrary to **isKeyguardSecure()** return `false` if:

- The user has unlocked the Lockscreen and is using the device
- The Smart Lock feature (Settings -> Security -> Smart Lock) allows the device to be unlocked without further authentication

**public boolean isKeyguardSecure ()**

This method does NOT take the current UI state of the Lockscreen into account.

So if a secure Screen Lock has been setup, it will always return `true`, regardless of if the Lockscreen has been unlocked by the user or if Smart Lock allows unlock without further authentication.

I was not able to reproduce the behavior reported by ByteHamster btw.

Comment: Would be more interesting to compare KeyguardManager.isDeviceLocked() with KeyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked(). I haven't found answer yet