# isKeyguardLocked vs isDeviceLocked

Tags: android, keyguard

I'm currently facing a troublesome bug with some Android Devices. I'm checking up on KeyguardManager to see if I need to disable audio or not (I want the audio be disabled whenever the game is not active or screen is locked etc.)

I've been using `isDeviceLocked` method to see if the user has access or not.

But now I found a device that continuously reports that `isDeviceLocked' == true.

Android docs says

> boolean isDeviceLocked ()
>
> Returns whether the device is currently locked and requires a PIN, pattern or password to unlock.
>
> boolean isKeyguardLocked ()
>
> Return whether the keyguard is currently locked.

What's the difference between isDeviceLocked and isKeyguardLocked, except for that they were added in different SDK versions?

Comment: Maybe it's a duplicate answer. Reference this link [What's the difference between isDeviceLocked and isKeyguardSecure in android's KeyguardManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053876/8063624)

Answer (score 9):

The isDeviceLocked() method returns true only when the device is locked and requires a PIN, pattern or password to unlock. The isKeyguardLocked() method is similar but it will also return true if the device is locked without any security.