# Keyguard, isDeviceLocked or isDeviceSecured?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to develop an app which has a few security options, and for one of those options I need to able to know if the device is locked with any kind password(numbers,pattern,etc) so I started reading the android documentation and  found two KeyguardManager methods, isDeivceLocked() and isDeviceSecured() however  I don't really see much of a difference in the description, so what really is the difference between the two? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The [official API states the difference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html), though it might be a bit confusing. The key difference is whether you want to know the general configuration of the device, or its current state.

So `isDeviceLocked()` returns true if the device is **currently** locked behind some kind of password or identification mechanism, which is required in order to unlock and use the device. It returns false in case that the device is currently open and in use, or that it just doesn't require any password/identification in order to open it. (reference and more details may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053876/997940))

On the other hand, `isDeviceSecure()` returns true if the device has been configured to use any kind of password or identification mechanism - even if it's not currently required in order to use the device.

In case you wonder what scenario might cause `isDeviceSecure` to return true, while `isDeviceLocked` returns false: it might happen whenever the device in in use (after the lock password has already been entered). Another scenario might be when the device has [Smart Unlock](https://www.howtogeek.com/202881/use-smart-locks-in-android-5.0-and-never-unlock-your-phone-at-home-again/) (or trusted devices) configured, so that currently it wouldn't ask for a password or any other kind of identification in order to open/unlock itself.