# Show toast every time after user passed the lock screen using React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm totally new on React Native and I'm struggling to create an app that shows a temporary message(2-3 sec) every time I pass the lock screen(by PIN or Finger Print). How to approach it? Any suggestion can be helpful.

Comment: Not exactly a good fit for ReactNative-  it has no UI component and requires deep integration with the phone.  You'd be better off doing it in pure java, you're almost certain to need a custom Java module in the end anyway.  For the Java way see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on, you'd need to translate that to react native somehow.

Comment: Using Toast in react-native is very simple.. If you want to use it in `ioS and Android` then you can use package `react-native-simple-toast`, or if you want to use it only on `Android` then there is a default Api from facebook `ToastAndroid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-easy-toast npm library to handle this issue. popping up message as toast. [Easy toast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-easy-toast)