# what callback is called after device unlock for ViewGroup?

Tags: android

I already tried onWindowFocusChanged, onLayout callback but it doesn't get called when lock/unlock device very quickly

Comment: Can you explain *"device unlock for ViewGroup"*? Do you just want to know when the device is unlocked? [This *might* be what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)

Comment: @codeMagic I need to know what method is called after lock and unlock the device in ViewGroup itself

Comment: If your activity is open, then onResume should run

Comment: @codeMagic I am asking the callback of ViewGroup, actually onWindowFocusChanged or onLayout gets called when press lock/unlock button slowly but not get called when press it very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try using your Activity's life cycle callback methods. When the device is unlocked, `onResume()` is called as your Activity is becoming visible.

Comment: I have built custom view using FrameLayout and need to set bitmap to image view again when device is unlocked