# Callback on change Screen lock

Tags: android, security, keyguard, screen-lock, google-pay

I need some advice about Screen lock on Android. 
Does android sent some intent when user change Screen lock?
Or I need poll KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecured in Service?

Google pay send a notification when user remove Screen lock, i need exactly the same behavior.

Comment: You are going to need a **BroadCast Reciever**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: This work only for android lower O (API 26).

Comment: I need check Screen lock changes when application is stopped or destroyed