# How to get / fetch phone device lock and unlock count in android programming?

Tags: android

How to get/fetch phone device lock and unlock count daily, weekly and monthly??
Need to fetch the number of times an Android device has been locked and unlocked. 
Need Code example for calculating the total number of times the device has been locked or unlocked in android Language.!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: No one will provide you code . You need to code yourself we can only help if you have some problem with code .. Follow this link and Hands on keyboard....