# How can i redirect my app to a lock screen when reenter app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, lockscreen, resume

My App could be locked with pin or fingerprint. I was able to do this on App Start with an "Start Up" Activity handle the pin/fingerprint stuff. But when it is once handled it is unlocked. But I want that when app was in background the lock screen is shown when the app is resumed. How can i manage this?

I was trying to start an intent when `OnResume()` of MainActivity is called.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, StartUpActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);

}
```

But then it goes to an infinity loop ... :(. And with the resume I can not distinguish whether i came from another activity in my app or if the app was getting back in foreground.

I was also searching a bit but i didn't find a solution to this problem. If i was missed a solution, please provide a link.

Thanks, 
Sebi

Comment: just use something like this I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: It is not that i want to know when the phone is unlocked/locked but when my app comes to foreground and then redirekt to my startup activity. But without the infinity loop. but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do the check described in this answer: [How to detect when an Android app goes to the background and come back to the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo)

With this I could check if the app came from the background or from an internal activity. 
And then I could call the Intent to my Start Up Activity.

Answer (score 1):

`onResume` is a proper place to start. But you need to add also something which handles lock/unlock logic and define non-lockable screens to avoid loops.

`Lock/unlock` logic could be placed into something like `PinManager`

```
interface PinManager {

  /**
   * it's up to you how to define logic inside.
   * It could be locked after some time 
   * or locked when app is destroyed and removed from memory
   */
  fun isLocked():Boolean

  fun unlock(pin:List<Integer>)

  fun clear()
}
```

To avoid loops you can define interface:

```
interface NonLockedActivity {

}
```

And use it with actvity which verifies pin:

```
class VerifiyPinActivity: BaseActivity(), NonLockedActivity {
  fun verifiy(pin:List<Int>){

    if(pinManager.unlock(pin)){
      finish()//and show previous activity
    } else {
      //show invalid pin message
    } 
  }
}
```

and in base activities `onResume` could look like this

```
class BaseActivity: Activity(){
  fun onResume(){

    if(pinManager.isLocked()){
      navigator.verifyPin(this)
    }

  }
}
```

And hide implementation of opening activity in `navigator`:

```
class Navigator {
  fun verifyPin(acitvity:Activity) {
    if(activity is not NonLockedActivity) {
      startActivity(VerifiyPinActivity::class)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was doing a similar thing to avoid loops but the problem with this was, that i could't distinguish if the app was in background or the onStart()/onResume() was called from an internal activity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of how you've done your pin locking.

From the question I assume you've used some library or self made approach for that. In this case you may store some value `isLocked` in `SharedPreferences` and change it every time in `onDestroy` or in `onStop` to `true`. When user enters your app you should check if `isLocked == true` and prompt pin screen and change it to false on successful unlock, and if `isLocked == false` you can proceed with you app flow. If you want this to do it easier way - you may just have some static variable and manipulate its value - but on the app process recreation it will be changed to default value.

But I would recommend you to look into these methods - they are default for the Android OS.

With [`KeyguardManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) you should use `Intent intent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(title, description)` in conjunction with `startActivityForResult(intent)` which will handle all the stuff you need and in `onActivityResult` you can handle moving forward.

Starting from API 28 you can use [`BiometricPrompt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.html). You can use its `Builder`'s method `setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)` that will handle the pin stuff in similar way as `KeyguardManager` only with face/fingerprint options. `BiometricPrompt` has method `authenticate` that will actually prompt pin screen. It receives listener as argument so you won't need `onActivityResult`.

Comment: That is an interesting point, i will look into the KeyguardMangager. And you are right I use my own Activity for displaying and handling the PIN/Fingerprint stuff.