# Detect Mobile Unlock event in my application in both android and ios [nativescript]

Tags: nativescript

I need to detect Mobile Unlock event in my application ( That will be either running all the time  or will resume at unlock) . Can you suggest what should i do? Thanks.

Comment: Please give more details about the situation.

Comment: Is one of these appropriate for you? https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#use-application-events

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box event that you can directly hook to. However, you can use the native solutions in NativeScripty (of course, you will need to convert the code to JavaScript/TypeScrit using the NativeScript marshaling)  .Example of how native Android devs are handling the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: In Android you could use a BroadcastReceiver to detect unlock, just like @NickIliev pointed. I don't think iOS allows anything as such, but with iOS 13.x and later, you may use BGAppRefreshTask for long running background tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help .. i will check and circle back .