# How to count unlocks in android while app closed?

Tags: java, android

I want to count the amount of unlocks, now there are post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on), but they don't explain how to efficiently count unlocks while the app is closed, can I get any code examples? I have tried to use background services, but I don't want a notification constantly displayed while the unlocks are counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers). The filter you're looking for is [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_USER_PRESENT).

In your `onReceive()` function is triggered, you can load the current number from [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), add one and save it back.

Comment: no need for services or something like that?

Comment: no, I think you don't need an ongoing running process or service, you just need to get triggered, execute your bit of code and exit!